# Fvwm Vector Buttons

Tags: window-manager, window, window-management, window-decorations, fvwm

I am trying to add windows buttons to my decor. (button numbers `1` `6` `4` `2`)

```
AddToDecor MyWDecor
+ AddButtonStyle 1 Vector 7 70x15@0 30x55@1 50x55@0 40x85@1 80x45@0 60x45@1 70x15@0
+ AddButtonStyle 2 Vector 17 20x20@1 30x20@1 50x40@1 70x20@1 80x20@1 80x30@0 60x50@0 80x70@1 80x80@0 70x80@0 50x60@0 30x80@0 20x80@0 20x70@0 40x50@1 20x30@0 20x20@1
+ AddButtonStyle 4 Vector 5 25x25@1 25x75@1 75x75@0 75x25@0 25x25@1
+ AddButtonStyle 6 Vector 10 40x55@1 40x80@0 15x80@0 15x55@1 40x55@1 30x55@1 30x30@1 70x30@1 70x70@1 45x70@1

Mouse 0 2       A       Menu MenuFvwmWindowOps2 Close
Mouse 0 4       A       FuncFvwmMaximize
Mouse 0 6       A       Iconify
```

But it doesn't draw buttons that I stated. It just draw a big square for 6 a little one for 2 and a dot for 6.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a question for FVWM1 or FVWM2?  Here is how I added a custom button of an arrow pointing down to my FVWM1 `.fvwmrc` file:

```
ButtonStyle : 1 8 40x20@1 40x50@1 20x50@1 50x80@1 80x50@0 60x50@0 60x20@0 40x20@1
```

This makes, in the upper left corner of all of the windows, an arrow pointing down.  Now, it's also important that this button is visible, so we also have something like this in the `.fvwmrc`:

```
Mouse 0     1       A       Iconify
```

`Mouse 0` means "any mouse button".  "1" indicates the button to be pressed.  Since the number is odd, FVWM1 automatically puts it in the top left of a window.  "A" means "any keyboard button (Ctrl/Alt [called "M" for "Meta" in `fvwmrc` files] can also be specified).  `Iconify` means make the window an icon.

Note that FVWM will not draw a button unless there is something to do when the button is pressed.  By making the second field a number, it goes on a titlebar, which has buttons arranged thusly: 1357-----8642

Comment: it is Fvwm 2.6 . the stable

Comment: I never made the FVWM1 -> FVWM2 jump (When I tried FVWM2, the daemon which implemented focus-follows-mouse was buggy, so I went back to FVWM1 and stayed there until it became too time-consuming to figure out how to connect to a wireless network without Gnome's GUI)

Comment: First;Come back and see how great it is. I even help you with the Wifi

Comment: 1.the difference between AddbuttonStyle and Buttontyle?

Comment: 2.Mouse 0     1       A       Iconify means that I have press any key on keybord in addition to click?

Comment: Nope.  Here, you just click on the mouse...0 means "any mouse button".